# Finding partial sum of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to find sum of n terms of series: $$-1 +2-3+4-5+6 .... $$ Which is in the form $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}k$$
I am not sure how i should approach this

Comment: Differentiate two cases when n is even and odd.

Comment: Hem, $-1,1,-2,2,-3,3,\cdots$ maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=0}^nr^k$.  This is famously known as the geometric series:

$$S_n(r)=\sum_{k=0}^nr^k=\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

If we take the derivative of both sides, we end up with

$$S_n'(r)=\sum_{k=1}^nkr^{k-1}=\frac d{dr}\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$$

Let $r=-1$ and multiply both sides by $-1$ to get

> $$\sum_{k=1}^nk(-1)^k=-\left(\frac d{dr}\frac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}\bigg|_{r=-1}\right)$$

Comment: Well, this certainly works.  But that is a lot of effort for something so "Simply Beautiful."  ;-))  (+1)

Comment: @Dr.MV IMHO, the most beautiful answer was already taken (\**drats!*\*)

Comment: @Dr.MV Lol, it happens all the time :-(

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Notice
$$
(-1+2) + (-3+4) + \ldots = 1 + 1 + \ldots
$$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen \*cough\* finite sums \*cough\*

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Oh yeah. Man, I'm off today. Caught me twice. Deleted comment. \*sigh\*, I gotta pick up my slack

Answer (score 1):

Work out your partial sums.

$S_1 = -1 $

$S_2 = -1 + 2 = 1$

$S_3 = S_2 - 3 = -2$

$S_4 = S_2 + 4 = 2$

$S_5 = S_4 -5 = -3$

$S_6 = S_2 + 6 = 3$

Clearly this pattern continues.

You can find two separate expressions, one for n even and one for n odd,

OR you can use the "floor" or "ceiling" function

$\lfloor{(n-1)/2} \rfloor$ = greatest integer $\leq (n-1)/2$, or

or $\lceil (n/2) \rceil = $ least integer $\geq (n/2)$

With one of these expressions and $(-1)^n$, construct your formula for $S_n$.

Answer (score 1):

When $n$ is even, such as $$-1+2-3+4-5+6=\color{red}{-1+1}+1\color{red}{-3+3}+1\color{red}{-5+5}+1=3$$ 
So inductively the total is $$\frac n2$$

When $n$ is odd, such as $$-1+2-3+4-5+6-7=\color{red}{-1+1}+1\color{red}{-3+3}+1\color{red}{-5+5}+1-7=-4$$
So inductively the total is $$-\frac{n+1}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $s(n)=-1 +2-3+4-5+6 ....+(-1)^nn = \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kn$

We now have that
$$s(n+1)=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^k(n+1)$$
$$s(n+1)=(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^kn+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k$$
$$s(n+1)=(-1)^{n+1}(n+1)+s(n)+\frac{1}{2}[(-1)^n - 1]$$
We can subtract $s(n)$ from both sides and get a finite difference equation which we can happily solve with any common technique